# How to get Mathjax HTML (using mathjax js) quality output using Mathjax-Node to SVG

Tags: node.js, svg, mathjax

**Following is the output when LaTeX is rendered using Mathjax on Chrome:**

[image]

**Following is the output when LaTeX is rendered using Mathjax-Node and exported as SVG:**

[image]

Exact same expressions, absolutely no change in configurations but the SVG output is not nearly as good as HTML output. The difference in how "sec", "cos" are rendered and triangle, angle are not aligned properly is clearly visible.

How can I get the exact same output using Mathjax-node as Mathjax HTML rendering?

Comment: The top one is using the MathJax TeX fonts, while the second one is using the STIX fonts.  So perhaps you want to tell MathJax-node to use the TeX fonts rather than STIX (though I thought that was the default).  Did you perhaps get the images mixed up?  In the browser, MathJax will use local STIX fonts in favor of web TeX fonts, so that could happen without a configuration change (whereas MathJax-node using STIX takes an explicit configuration).

Comment: @DavideCervone, you were correct, removing mentioning the font helped. The default however is TeX font and something I was looking for.